# How do I manage session timeout if I am using SVNKit?

Tags: java, session, timeout, svnkit

I am using SVNKit 1.7.8 java API.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.tmatesoft.svnkit</groupId>
        <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.8</version>
</dependency>
```

My problem is after user logs in, session expires after some time (about 5-10 mins later) and authentication is required again. I want to set this timeout to some large value so that there is no session timeout. But I can't find any such API... Any idea guys?